# How to get array data from one Click Method to another one

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, scope

Don't think i could be any newer to coding, so please forgive me for whats about to be asked.

Im currently writing a program that lets the user enter a desired amount of random numbers to be generated by Random via textBox (lets say 15 --> you get 15 random numbers), ranging from 1 to 1000.

When hitting the Button A, those randomized Numbers will be saved in Zahlenarray[](-->with the length of the number entered in the textbox) and displayed in label1.Text.

Then there's a  Button B, that, when clicked, should sort the Numbers from Zahlenarray[] via bubblesort and display them in label2.

My problem is now that the second Method (Button B_Click) doesnt have the contents of Zahlenarray from the Button A_Click Method.

Id like to pass this data by ref via the arguments, but fiddling with  public void (Object sender, EventArgs e) seems to get me in major trouble.

Can i add arguments after EventArgs e, ... or am i missing another way of getting data out f this "scope" (hope thats the right word)?

Both Methods are in the same class.

part of the code of Button A:

```
public void Button_Anzeigen_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            label1.Text = "";            
            int[] Zahlenarray = new int[Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text)];
```

Everything from Button B:

```
private void Button_Sortieren_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = "";
    label3.Text = "";
    int Speicher;

    for (int n = Zahlenarray.Length; n > 0; n--)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {


            if (Zahlenarray[i] > Zahlenarray[i + 1])
            {
                Speicher = Zahlenarray[i];
                Zahlenarray[i] = Zahlenarray[i + 1];
                Zahlenarray[i + 1] = Speicher;
                Speicher = 0;
            }
        }
    }


    foreach (int i in Zahlenarray)
    {
        label2.Text += i + "   ";

        if ((i % 9 == 0) && !(i == 0))
            label2.Text += "\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your array declaration outside of your buttona click handler so you can reference it inside your button b handler.

```
int[] Zahlenarray;
public void Button_Anzeigen_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        label1.Text = "";            
        Zahlenarray = new int[Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text)];
        ...
    }
```

Comment: That gives me a NullreferenceException when Button2 tries to loop through it at this point:  for (int n = Zahlenarray.Length; n > 0; n--)

Comment: @Flauschkatze  look carefully,you probably get that exception because u must have declared AND initialized another Zahlenarray in the handler...buttonB handler is looping through the class scoped one....

Comment: int[] Zahlenarray; is all the code i have set for the class (as the poster above suggested). the mentioned for-loop is the first encounter of Zahlenarray[] inside the B method.

Comment: yes but first you handle buttonA and did you do this - Zahlenarray = new int[Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text)]; or this - int[] Zahlenarray = new int[Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text)]; ? IN buttonA....

Comment: int[] Zahlenarray;
       
        public void Button_Anzeigen_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
        {            
            label1.Text = "";            
            int[] Zahlenarray = new int[Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text)]; Thats the current code for Button A

Comment: @Flauschkatze as terrybozzio said, look carefully. as he said, you reinitailized your array inside your buttonA handler int[] Zahlenarayy , my answer clearly states that you dont. Zahlenarray =...

Comment: thats why in buttonB handler you get exception....in buttonA change to this Zahlenarray = new int[Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text)];

Comment: It finally works. Can someone explain what the difference is (when leaving away the int)? Never seen this kind declaration.

Comment: @Flauschkatze well, its not a declaration!. int[] Zahlenaarry; <- this is declaration. Zahlenarray = new int[..] <- this is initialization

Comment: @Flauschkatze - now would be a great time to study the C# language, that will teach you the difference between declaration and initialisation.